# fastest indexOf function for strings

Tags: ios, string, performance

I am currently using following extension for a string to get the index for a specific string in a big string:

```
func indexOf(target: String, startIndex: Int) -> Int
{
    var startRange = advance(self.startIndex, startIndex)
    var range = self.rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start: startRange, end: self.endIndex))
    if let range = range {
        return distance(self.startIndex, range.startIndex)
    } else {
        return -1
    }
}
```

I am calling this many times and I have a performance issue.
Does anyone have an idea how to do the indexOf() faster ?
Currently I am doing this in swift. Will doing this in Objective-C and bridging give a better performance ? Or probably if possible include any C Code ? Any ideas ?

**UPDATE** more about the Background

- I have a long text, say with 5000 characters.
- The Text contains several Metadata tags beside from normal text. These Tags are like {{blabl{{ sdasdg }} abla}} ; [[bla bla|blabla]] ; {|bla|}.
- I like to remove them or format them in a specific way.
- I can't use regular expression for this, because regular expression does not support stacked expressions ({{ {{ {{ {{dsgasdg}} }}}} }} )

So I wrote my own functions, which works, but is very slow.

What I am actually doing is I go throught the text and I am simply searchiong for these tags. For this I need a base function like the following, to determine which tag is the first and at which position. When I found a tag I will go to the next and so on. I recognized, that this is my most timeconsuming part of all. Of course I am calling this also a lot of time.

```
func getStart(sText:String, alSearchPatterns:[String], ifrom:Int) -> (Pattern:String, index:Int) {

    var bweiter:Bool=true;

    var actualcharacter:Character;

    var returnPattern="";
    var returnIndex = -1;
    println("ifrom : " + String(ifrom));

    var indexfound:Int = -1;
            // finde ersten character der Patterns
            var bsuchepattern=true;

            for(var i=0;i<alSearchPatterns.count && bsuchepattern;i++){

                let sPattern=alSearchPatterns[i];
                let pattern_first_char=sPattern[0];
                //let pattern_first_char=String(sPattern[0]);

                let characterIndex = sText.indexOfCharacter(pattern_first_char, fromIndex: ifrom); // find(sText, pattern_first_char);
                //let characterIndex = sText.indexOf(pattern_first_char, startIndex: ivon);

                if(characterIndex != -1){
                    if((indexfound == -1) || characterIndex < indexfound){
                        // found something that is first of all actually.
                        let patternlength=sPattern.length;
                        let substring_in_text=sText.substring(characterIndex, endIndex: characterIndex + patternlength);
                        if(substring_in_text.equals(sPattern)){
                            returnPattern=sPattern;
                            returnIndex=characterIndex;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        return (returnPattern,returnIndex);
}
```

Any hints how to do this more performant or any hints on how to do this better in general.

Comment: What are the sizes of the source strings, and the targets you're searching for? How many times do you call this function? What do the strings look like? There's plenty of room for improvement, but it depends on what your data is.

Comment: A question like this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for helping Cyrille. I updated my question to give more information on this. Would be happy if you could look on it :-)